# Is there a way to check for ambiguous methods in C# reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am writing a tool to make writing console applications in C# easier for me. For this I am trying to have a command parser dynamically (using reflection) attempt a look-up of a method name of another object (which extends or is of the class CommandUI) based on a command given. However, if I wanted to overload a method on that object and then access one of the overloaded methods from the command parser it would throw a AmbiguousMethodException while trying to find it by reflection. The tool will have no way of knowing what methods are contained at compile time. Is there a way to check for a method ambiguity in reflection other than enclosing Type.GetMethod(string name) in a try...catch block and catching an AmbiguousMethodException?

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could call `Type.GetMethods()` which will return _all_ methods, then see if you get more than one that matches the name: `Type.GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "MyMethodName").Count() > 1` (there's probably a more elegant way, and could be optimized a bit, but it would probably work.)

Comment: Also, there are overloads of `GetMethod` you can use to disambiguate the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using LINQ to pick the method rather than using the builtin filter options (name, binding flags, parameter types, etc.). The builtin flags are quite limited. For example, I could see a library like the one you're describing doign something like the following:

```
// user invoked "foo -format json -url www.google.com
// your code does something like:
var args = new[] { "format", "url" };
var matchingMethods = typeof(SomeType).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(t))
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods())
    .Where(m => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(m.Name, "foo"))
    .Where(m => {
        var parameters = m.GetParameters();
        var isValid = parameters.All(p => p.IsOptional || args.Contains(p.Name))
            && args.All(a => parameters.Any(p.Name == a));
        return isValid;
    })
    .ToArray();
```

With LINQ, you have ultimate flexibility to take all information into account and filter as you need.